# Display form field value on another html page, after submit

Tags: javascript, html

I really need help... :-) I have two html pages and forms on both of them. I need solution to show field value from first form (on first page) in field on second form, after click on SEND button. But, I need both pages to stay open, on first I need to insert values and on second page that values should be shown. Also, I need a solution without PHP because this app will be running on local devices, without server. I don't have any solution and please, I need some tips how I can do that.

I found here some solutions with localStorage and it looks interested but I need to stay on First page and send field value to Second page, in live. There is code which I found here, this is example what I need, just I need both pages to be open and after I insert some value in field on first page and click on button, that value should be shown in field on second page. Thank you in advance!

```
<html>
<head>
<title>First Page</title>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
 function saveVal() {
    var inputFirst = document.getElementById("name").value;
    localStorage.setItem("name", inputFirst);
    inputFirst = localStorage.getItem("name");
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="secondPage.html" method="get">
<label> 
First Name:
<input name="name" size="20" maxlength="25" type="text" id="name" />
</label>

<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="saveVal()"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>


<html>
<head>
<title>Second Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="#">
<label>
First Name:
<input name="name" size="20" maxlength="25" type="text" id="name" 
readonly="readonly" />
</label>

<script type="text/javascript">
 var storedVal = document.getElementById("name");
    storedVal.value = localStorage.getItem("name");
</script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, I would like to help you but your logic is not very clear, a user can not be on two pages at a time, it is necessary that this second page is consulted to know that the data is there.
Or I did not understand you correctly?

Comment: `without server` not sure this is possible...It sounds like you want a pub/sub model for updating data for users. Not sure how you plan to propagate that data across pages without a server.

Comment: How do you expect 2 pages to be opened at the same time? you cannot. Unless they are tabs or html divs (single page app) where you can switch back and forth but still you will only see one page/form at a time. I'm lost!

Comment: Yes, I need two pages to be opened, I will explain :-). On first page I should insert some numbers and second page should show to all users what I insert in first form. I will insert numbers in <input> field in first form and those values will be displayed on another page, another screen in <marquee> field. This is web app, not internet page and it will work on local network. I hope you unerstand me better now...

Answer (score 0):

You can use setInterval to constantly check and set the value:

```
//this will run storeCheck function every 250 miliseconds and update values from localStorage.

setInterval(storeCheck, 250);

function storeCheck() {
    var storedVal = document.getElementById("name");
    storedVal.value = localStorage.getItem("name");
}
```